# Re-Sort a ListView in C# - UWP

Tags: c#, sorting, listview, uwp

I've created a XAML UWP Listview

```
            <ListView x:Name="ThisList" 
                  Grid.Row="3"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
                  Background="LightBlue"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="2"
                  ItemClick="ThisList_ItemClick">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <local:ColourConverter x:Key="CCX"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" MinWidth="500"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border Background="Aquamarine" Grid.Column="0">
                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="{Binding Icon}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="Yellow" Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock Name="tbFileName" Text="{Binding FName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="Cyan" Grid.Column="2">
                            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding FTime}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FTime}"
                                       Name="FileTime"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Foreground="{Binding ElementName=FileTime,
                                                            Path=Text, 
                                                            Mode=OneWay, 
                                                            Converter={StaticResource CCX}}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="Tomato" Grid.Column="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The code behind is

```
        var folderItem = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();
        foreach (StorageFolder folder in folderList)
        {
            BasicProperties pro = await folder.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
            folderItem.Add(new FolderInfo()
            {
                FName = folder.DisplayName,
                FSize = "",
                FTime = lastFileSave,
                FIsFolder = true                    
            });
        }

        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            BasicProperties pro = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
            lastFileSave = file.DateCreated.ToString(Globals.TimeFormat);
            folderItem.Add(new FolderInfo()
            {
                //FName = file.DisplayName,
                FName = file.Name,
                FSize = GetFileSize(pro.Size),
                FTime = lastFileSave,
                FIsFolder = false,
                Icon="Document"
            });

        }
        showLoadingBox(false);
        FileInfo.Text += $"Last file saved : {lastFileSave}";
        ThisList.ItemsSource = folderItem;
```

So my question is that I'd like to create a header row that I can click on the title and it re-sorts the ListView by that column, and if I click again it re-sorts descending.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-how-to-column-sorting/ would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately that page only with WPF forms and not with the UWP that I'm using.

Comment: That you're doing UWP is pretty important info. You might want to edit your question and add that.

Comment: My apologies - have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there was no rush of answers so I have created a separate grid to make the header, and added a tapped event to requery the data source, but to do a query on it as it is assigned to the listview source as follows.

```
ThisList.ItemsSource = (from FolderInfo in folderItem
                                        orderby FolderInfo.RealDateTime
                                        select FolderInfo);
```

It's probably not the most efficient way of doing things, but currently the only way I can see of doing it without the ListView having some kind of sort method available.

Would appreciate any comments if there is a better way of doing it.